# Should I define a destructor for a derivate of QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, destructor

I would like to know if I should define a destructor of a derivate of `QWidget`.
Example

```
class CustomWidget : public QWidget{
    QLabel* field;
    CustomWidget(QWidget* parent) : 
        QWidget( parent ), 
        field( new QLabel(this) ) {};
}
```

I've already read about the "Widget tree" that will call the destructor of all the child if the parent is destructed, but i mean, just to be sure

Comment: Does your widget allocate any memory that needs to be freed?

Comment: @JarMan since there is a `new`...

Comment: I said "that needs to be freed". The QLabel in your example will automatically get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given one, no. The parenting system will take care of `field`. But u should add `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: what do that macro will do?

Comment: @Berto99 Since the class inherits from `QObject`, the macro should be added (there may be a strange behavior in the parenting system due to that).

Comment: @Berto99 [see](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html)

Comment: `But u must add Q_OBJECT macro.` is not true. This is only required if you need the generated meta data for something, such as defining your own signals.